# How often does macOS synch my computer clock?

Tags: macos, time

Just curious on how often this occurs and what is the process?  Also, is there a time server that I can connect to using an API of sorts?

Answer (score 4):

As standard, the time is synchronized approx. every 20 minutes. This is done by the process `timed`.

Yes, you can connect to Apple's time servers if you like. You can check which server your computer is setup to use by inspecting the file `/etc/ntp.conf`. Apple's' servers are named for example `time.apple.com`, `time.euro.apple.com`, `time2.apple.com` and so on.

Apple's servers are nothing special in that regard - you can find online time servers from many places such as `time.google.com`, `time.facebook.com`, `time.windows.com`, etc. A popular one is the NTP Pool Project, which features NTP servers all around the globe for public usage. Point your request to `0.pool.ntp.org`, `1.pool.ntp.org` and so on to get the current time.

The protocol used to connect to these time servers is known as [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) (Network Time Protocol). The [communication protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5905) is standardized and freely available.

Comment: If you want to force a recalibration with NTP, just kill the `timed` process in Activity Monitor, or by using command line `Kill` with the process id, or `pkill timed` for a fast and easy execution. This forces `timed` to restart and query NTP afresh.

Comment: Is this atomic time or UTC time?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7806757

Comment: When you display the time on your Mac, people mostly want to show their own time zone or UTC. It is not common to use TAI (atomic time). Note that converting back and forth between UTC and TAI is just something that happens on your local computer - similar to how you can select various time zones. You don’t need a different NTP server for showing the time in TAI versus UTC. So you can do whatever you want for your purpose